# Zned 2 How to override FormElementErrors

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to override global these vars:

\Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElementErrors.php
Form:

```
protected $messageCloseString     = '</li></ul>';
protected $messageOpenFormat      = '<ul%s><li>';
protected $messageSeparatorString = '</li><li>';
```

To:

```
protected $messageCloseString     = '</li></ul>';
protected $messageOpenFormat      = '<ul%s><li class="errors">';
protected $messageSeparatorString = '</li><li>';
```

How can i do this?
Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that settings global, you can create your own factory for this (or any other) view helper:

```php
<?php

namespace Application\Factory\Form\View\Helper;

use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElementErrors;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class FormElementErrorsFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $helper = new FormElementErrors();
        $helper->setMessageOpenFormat('<ul%s><li class="errors">');

        return $helper;
    }
}
```

And override configuration of `ViewHelperManager`:

```php
<?php
// module.config.php

return [
    'view_helpers' => [
        'factories' => [
            'formelementerrors' => \Application\Factory\Form\View\Helper\FormElementErrorsFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Now you can use `formElementErrors` view helper as usual, but with your custom configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can set any part of message format by calling setters in this helper on top of Your view file:

```
<?php
$this->formElementErrors()
    ->setMessageOpenFormat('<p class="help-block">')
    ->setMessageSeparatorString('</p><p class="help-block">')
    ->setMessageCloseString('</p>');
```

This example format error messages for TW Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks, but i want them to be global, so i can set them once for all the forms. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, just extend formElementErrors helper by your own class, and in this extended class implement your own format form error messages and then register it in module config and use as origin one.

Answer (score 0):

Thnx! Awnser 1 en 2 combined, gives:

```
namespace Application\Factory\Form\View\Helper;

use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElementErrors;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class FormElementErrorsFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $helper = new FormElementErrors();
    $helper->setMessageOpenFormat('<ul%s><li class="errors">');

    return $helper;
}
}

//module.config

'view_helpers' => array(
'invokables'=> array(
    'formelementerror' => '\Admin\Factory\Form\View\Helper\FormElementErrorsFactory'
)
),

//view.phtml
$element = $this->formElementErrors()
->setMessageOpenFormat('<p class="help-block">')
->setMessageSeparatorString('</p><p class="help-block">')
->setMessageCloseString('</p>');
foreach ($form as $element) {        
echo '<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">';
echo $this->formElement($element);
echo '</div></div>';
echo $this->formElementErrors($element);
}
echo $this->form()->closeTag();?>
```